# Ввод/вывод python.py-скриптам в консоли linux

Tags: python, linux, centos, shell

В консоли linux не выводится результат работы python-скриптов

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print("Hello")
```

Через подключение библиотеки sys тоже ничего не получается

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.stdout.write("Hello")
```

Также в скрипте есть цикл, который требует ввода с клавиатуры и завершается, если введено **"exit"**, но никаких данных я ввести не могу

```
#...
while True:
string = input()
#...
```

Использовать **<<** или **<<<** неудобно? Причем, я не могу проверить работоспособность, так как не вижу вывода в консоль.

Comment: Быть такого не может. Я проверил оба ваших скрипта - строка `Hello` исправно выводится (Pyhton 2.7.17, Ubuntu 18). Как вы запускаете скрипты? Какая версия Python? Какая версия Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно в строке шибанг вам стоит поставить пробел после "!".
Можно еще попробовать наглядно указать какая версия питона должна использоваться.
Например:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
print("Hello")
```

И приложите пожалуйста скрин терминала попытки запуска скрипта.

А лучше вам убрать из скрипта строку шибанг, в расширении файла скрипта указать "*.py" и в терминале просто запускать его через обращение к интерпритатору python.
Например:

```
python myscript.py
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).